# PyTorch: Computing the norm of batched tensors

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have tensor `t` with shape (Batch_Size x Dims) and another tensor `v` with shape (Vocab_Size x Dims).  I'd like to produce a tensor `d` with shape (Batch_Size x Vocab_Size), such that `d[i,j] = norm(t[i] - v[j])`.

Doing this for a single tensor (no batches) is trivial: `d = torch.norm(v - t)`, since `t` would be broadcast.  How can I do this when the tensors have batches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert unitary dimensions into `v` and `t` to make them (1 x Vocab_Size x Dims) and (Batch_Size x 1 x Dims) respectively. Next, take the broadcasted difference to get a tensor of shape (Batch_Size x Vocab_Size x Dims). Pass that to `torch.norm` along with the optional `dim=2` argument so that the norm is taken along the last dimension. This will result in the desired (Batch_Size x Vocab_Size) tensor of norms.

```py
d = torch.norm(v.unsqueeze(0) - t.unsqueeze(1), dim=2)
```

Edit: As pointed out by @KonstantinosKokos in the comments, due to the [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) used by numpy and pytorch, the leading unitary dimension on `v` does not need to be explicit. I.e. you can use

```py
d = torch.norm(v - t.unsqueeze(1), dim=2)
```

Comment: You only need to unsqueeze the `t` tensor I reckon; broadcasting only cares about trailing dimensions.